# Conditional WHERE statement in Laravel's Query Builder doesn't work with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For my database `table`, while the code below works fine:

```php
$sql = DB::table('table')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->limit(50)->get();
```

with 50 rows, this doesn't:

```php
$sql = DB::table('table')->select('id');
$sql->orderBy('id', 'asc')->limit('50')->get();
```

as it does return with the correct rows, but it returns all rows in the database itself. I need to be able to seperate it, as I intend to have if statements in between to add `WHERE` clauses depending on the user input like so (EDIT: Added code similar to actual code):

```php
$foo = $request->input('foo');
$bar = $request->input('bar');

$sqls = DB::table('foobar')->select('id', 'name', 'age', 'zip_code');

if($foo === "foo") $sqls->where('age', '<', 31);
if($bar === "bor") $sqls->where('zip_code', '>', '12345');

$sqls->orderBy('age', 'asc')->limit(50)->get();

$return = '';

$sqls->each(function($sql) use (&$return){
     $return .= "<td> {$sql->id} </td>"
}
```

returns all rows rather than limiting to 50 rows.

Comment: I'm assuming that this isn't your actual code and you've simplified it for the sake of your question? If this is the case please can you show your actual code. Currently, it isn't clear why there would be an issue.

Comment: @Rwd It's pretty much the same, but I added the actual code with some variables changed.

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I'm sorry if I'm missing something but it still isn't very clear what your problem is. The code you have should do what you want it to do. The only thing I am noticing is that you're not assigning the results of the query to anything. What version of Laravel are you using and what version of PHP do you have?

Comment: @Rwd I'm using v7.3.12, and Laravel v6.6.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that the above code returns more than 50 results?

Comment: @Rwd correct, it returns all rows in the table.

Comment: Ok. As I've said it isn't clear how your checking this as you're not assigning the results to a variable nor do you seem to be returning them. Please can you show the code your using to check this.

Comment: And there's the issue. I'll write up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're calling `each` on the query builder instance not the results from the query (which would be a collection). `each()` on the query builder is for chunking the results which will ignore any limit you may have previously set.

Firstly, to get the code you have working you can assign the results to a variable and then call `each()` on that.

```
$results = $sqls->orderBy('age', 'asc')->limit(50)->get();

$results->each(...);
```

However, I would actually recommend you use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-map) and [join()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-join) instead of [each()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-each):

```
$results = $sqls->orderBy('id', 'asc')->limit(10)->get();

$return = $results->map(function ($item) {
    return  "<td> {$item->id} </td>";
})->join('');
```

---

Just an FYI, Laravel also has a [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses) method to save you having to write multiple if statements so you entire query could look like:

```
$results = DB::table('foobar')
    ->select('id', 'name', 'age', 'zip_code')
    ->when($request->input('foo') === 'foo', function ($query) {
        $query->where('age', '<', 31);
    })
    ->when($request->input('bar') === 'bar', function ($query) {
        $query->where('zip_code', '>', '12345');
    })
    ->orderBy('age', 'asc')
    ->limit(50)
    ->get();

$return = $results->map(function ($item) {
    return  "<td> {$item->id} </td>";
})->join('');
```

Comment: @Dragonsnap Glad I could help! All I would say is in the future don't try and simplify your code too much as it can end up masking the actual issue like it has done here :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you

```
if($request->input('var')) {
   $var = $request->var;
   $cond1 = DB::table('table')->select('...')->where('foo','>',$var)- 
             >orderBy()->limit()->get();
 // more if 
}
```

Comment: Edited; That's not the problem, just a typo.

Comment: I want to be able to have more `if` and `WHERE` clauses if I want, calling `get()` after it only met 1 `if` statement doesn't work for me.